# Decryption Algorithm Python

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption

Let's say you have a text file that contains a few encrypted words.
You don't know the encryption algorithm, but you know that the method that the encryption uses its just replacing every letter with another one.

Lets say we've got a regular word, 'Speaker', and after the encryption it became 'nHudtrl'.

My question is, what is the algorithm to decrypt this kind of encryption? Is it an algorithm that will go through every word and try another word? I tried that below and it didn't work.

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

wordt = {}
wordlist_lower = [l for l in letters]
wordlist_upper = [l.upper() for l in letters]

def GENE(word):
    for string in word:
        for letter in wordlist_lower:
            wordt[string] = letter
            print('{}| \'{}\' --- {}'.format(word, string, wordt))
            if letter == 'z':
                del wordt[string]
GENE('Speaker')


def GENE2(word):
    for string in word:
        for letter in wordlist_upper:
            wordt[string] = letter
            print('{}| \'{}\' --- {}'.format(word, string, wordt))
            if letter == 'Z':
                del wordt[string]
GENE2('Speaker')
```

If you run this you will see that it's basically iterating through every letter in 'Speaker' and printing each letter, both lower and upper.

How do I write an algorithm like this, but that actually works?

Comment: Please be more clear. What about your code is lacking? Is the expected behavior different from the observed? How?

Comment: This is a substitution cipher. If you have a ciphertext plaintext pair (a word that you know it and its encryption), it is easy to retrieve parts of the key. Otherwise, with a large enough set of encrypted messages, frequency analysis can be applied.

Comment: This is a classic problem -- there's no strict algorithm, but you can look at the frequency of the letters in the ciphertext and compare them to norms for the natural language which you think may have been used to write the plaintext.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis

Comment: What i was trying to achieve when i wrote this code, is to decrypt words that was encrypted with the 'letter replacement' method.
my code is just iterating thru letters

Comment: What problems are you having? With your description above it does seem to be a generic frequency analysis problem.

Comment: Without a plain-text/cypher-text pair, you would have to guess (i.e. freq. analysis) then either do lookups in a huge dictionary, , perform natural language analysis,  or get a human to assess the results. there's no quantitative way for your algorithm to know if it's right

Comment: There's gotta be a way to decrypt ecrypted messages encrypted with that method